# Strange PHP output

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I'm using this code to attempt to grab a table name and store it in a variable.

```
<?php
connectDB();
$sql = "SHOW TABLES";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$tables = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    foreach ($tables as $table) {
        $table_name = $table[0];
        echo $table_name;
    }
closeConn();
?>
```

For one, its outputting 'aa' and 'bb' if i change the array index which i know arent table names in the db and two, what i want to do is run some code for every table in the db and insert the table name into a variable which i can use in said code? How would i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$tables = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

`mysql_fetch_array` fetches one row, not the entire set. This means that when you do `$table[0]`, you are actually working on the string value of each field in the row.

You should put the `mysql_fetch_array` inside the loop instead:

```
while ($table = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $table_name = $table[0];
    echo $table_name;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend `echo "$table_name\n";`

Comment: thanks, this got it! Any idea why this would only print out two of the 3 tables starting with the second one and ignoring the first one?

Comment: @StasM I presume this isn't the final purpose of `$table_name`, but yes, that's probably a good suggestion.

Comment: @benhowdle89 My code? No, no idea. What happens if you do the query in a MySQL console/phpMyAdmin?

Comment: @benhowdle89 Make sure you've deleted the previous call to `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: HA! Yep that was it, what a div! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`SHOW TABLES` returns a table with one table name per row. You should use `mysql_fetch_array` as many times as there are rows in the table, because it only retrieves *one row* of the table...

Think of something like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $table_name = $row[0];
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$sql = "SHOW TABLES";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH))
{
    $tables[] = $row[0];
}

// To Display
foreach ($tables as $table) {

    $table_name = $table;
    echo $table_name;
}
```